# How to change default log directory on IIS [W3SVC]

Tags: iis, windows-server-2012

Normally IIS store logs based on the website ID directory
[image]

Is there any way to change the log directory to the website name?

[image: Website Logs]
[image: Website ID]

Instead of the W3SVC folder, I would like to have my custom folder,

For example, SchoolWebAPP , ID 7, i would like to have a SchoolWebAPP Log directory.

Anyone knows if this is possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Researched and found this advanced logging module.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/advanced-logging-module/advanced-logging-for-iis-custom-logging